# Mongodb - 100% cpu, 95%+ lock, low disk activity

Tags: arrays, performance, mongodb

I have a mongo database setup where I am running a lot of findAndModify-queries against. At first it was performing fine, doing ~400 queries and ~1000 updates per second (according to mongostat). This caused a 80-90% lock percentage, but it seemed reasonable given the amount of data throughput.

After a while it has slowed to a crawl and is now doing a meager ~20 queries / ~50 updates per second.

All of the queries are on one collection. The majority of the collections have a set of basic data (just key: value entries, no arrays or similar) that is untouched and then an array of downloads with the format + number of bytes downloaded. Example:

```
downloads: [
    {
        'bytes: 123131,
        'format': extra
    },
    {
        'bytes: 123131,
        'format': extra_hd
    }
    ...
]
```

A bit of searching tells me that big arrays are not good, but if the majority of documents only have 10-15 entries in this array (with a few outliers that have 1000+) should it still affect my instance this bad?

CPU load is near 100% constantly, lock % is near 100% constantly. The queries I use are indexed (I confirmed via `explain()`) so this should not be an issue.

Running `iostat 1` gives me the following:

```
        disk0       cpu     load average
  KB/t tps  MB/s  us sy id   1m   5m   15m
 56.86 122  6.80  14  5 81  2.92 2.94 2.48
 24.00   9  0.21  15  1 84  2.92 2.94 2.48
 21.33   3  0.06  14  2 84  2.92 2.94 2.48
 24.00   3  0.07  15  1 84  2.92 2.94 2.48
 33.14   7  0.23  14  1 85  2.92 2.94 2.48
 13.68 101  1.35  15  2 84  2.92 2.94 2.49
 30.00   4  0.12  14  1 84  2.92 2.94 2.49
 16.00   4  0.06  14  1 85  2.92 2.94 2.49
 28.00   4  0.11  14  2 84  2.92 2.94 2.49
 33.60   5  0.16  14  1 85  2.92 2.94 2.49
```

I am using mongodb 2.4.8, and while upgrading is an option I would prefer to avoid it. It is running on my local SSD disk on OS X. It will be transferred to run on a server, but I would like to fix or at least understand the performance issue before I move it.

Comment: Looking at this will of course be a **very** broad subject. But consider two things. 1.) MongoDB uses memory mapped storage, so most of the operations should occur in memory and MongoDB will love to eat up as much as possible. Even while it will periodically "flush" to disk (but journals will always be there) 2.) If you are profiling the performance of you application, then perhaps your best question is to ask about typical operations you do. So considering those points, ask yourself. Am I really asking a question someone can answer?

Comment: The first thing to look at is whether your indexing is adequate for your operations. Do you see slow operations in your log file? You can search for lines that end with "ms" to find them. A few things to look for are high "nscanned" values which could indicate a table scan and "scanAndOrder" having a value of true which means in-memory sort.